# Que signifie « j'ai plus que des balles à me tirer » dans la chanson « Amandine » de Saez ?

Tags: sens, paroles-de-chanson

Que veut dire « j'ai plus que des balles à me tirer » dans la contexte des [paroles](http://musique.ados.fr/Saez/Amandine-Ii-t13445.html) ci-dessous (une partie de la chanson Amandine de Saez) ?

> J'ai perdu l'amour de ma vie
>   J'ai perdu mon ange mon bébé
>   Mais depuis que t'es plus dans mon lit
>   J'ai plus que des balles à me tirer

Je comprends que le chanteur est triste parce qu'il a perdu Amandine et je vois qu'il ressent quelque chose maintenant qu'elle ne reste plus dans son lit.  Cependant, je ne comprends pas pourquoi il n'a plus que des balles à se tirer.  Est-ce qu'il songe à se suicider ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

« Je n'ai plus qu'à me tirer une balle » est l'expression plus habituelle pour dire qu'il est désespéré, et qu'il n'a plus rien d'autre à faire que de se suicider, comme tu le relèves.

Je pense que *j'ai plus que des balles à me tirer* est simplement une reformulation qui fait référence à cette expression-là, pour faire un rappel de la construction « je t'avais toi, mais maintenant, je n'ai plus que … ».

Autrement dit, **oui**, il dit que tout ce qu'il lui reste, c'est le suicide.

Comment: J'ai la vague impression qu'il pourrait y avoir une deuxième référence. La première à « se tirer des balles » (qui désigne plus souvent un dégout qu'une envie de suicide), et l'autre à la ligne précédente, à une expression — hum… —, disons particulièrement peu romantique, que l'auteur aurait pu songer à utiliser pour décrire ce qu'il se passait « avant » dans ce lit. Pas vraiment du meilleur style (pour ne pas dire goût), mais bon à voir le reste des paroles… j'ai quand même un doute.

Comment: Ah, oui, tiens, je n'avais pas fait attention, c'est vrai. Mais le *me* gêne, quand même, donc si c'est bien intentionnel, c'est secondaire par rapport à *se tirer des balles* (ou bien il aurait enlevé ce *me*). Enfin je crois.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Clairement, le vote du public abonde dans ton sens ; ça mérite peut-être une réponse. Ou bien j'éditerai la mienne, quand je repasserai par là, dans 2 autres années.